# How to make a python package containing only jinja templates

Tags: python, flask, pip, package, jinja2

Currently have a project where I am currently trying to extend jinja2 templates that live in a python package I am trying to make. Right now I'm struggling to make a python package with `.html` files. Here is what I currently have:

```
sharedtemplates/
├── setup.py
└── templates
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── base.html
    ├── footer.html
    └── header.html
```

`__init__.py` is empty and `setup.py` is super basic.

The directory I am currently working on is setup like this:

```
repo/
├── site.py
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

In `index.html` I would have `{% extends 'base.html' %}` to extend base in the `sharedtemplates` package.

`site.py` has this in there to prioritize the template loading:

```
template_loader = jinja2.ChoiceLoader([
    jinja2.PackageLoader('reposhared', 'templates'),
    app.jinja_loader
])

app.jinja_loader = template_loader
```

So this would load the templates dir in sharedtemplates/ first the templates/ in my current repo dir.

Thank you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Celeo Sorry I should have been clearer. I keep getting ImportError No module found. Is there something specific I would need in my sharetemplates/ module. From what I understand everything else seems okay.

Comment: I forgot to do `python setup.py install`. And I needed to throw the templates in another templates dir. So it is `sharedtemplates/templates/templates/base.html`. Definitely need to do some renaming and refactoring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to do python setup.py install. And I needed to throw the templates in another templates dir. So it is sharedtemplates/templates/templates/base.html. Definitely need to do some renaming and refactoring