# How to load jinja template directly from filesystem

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

The [jinja API document at pocoo.org](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#) states:

> The simplest way to configure Jinja2 to load templates for your application looks roughly like this:
>
> ```
> from jinja2 import Environment, PackageLoader
> env = Environment(loader=PackageLoader('yourapplication', templates'))
> ```
>
> This will create a template environment with the default settings and a loader that looks up the templates in the *templates* folder inside the *yourapplication* python package.

As it turns out, this isn't so simple because you have to make/install a python package with your templates in it, which introduces a lot of needless complexity, especially if you have no intention of distributing your code.

I found these related questions about doing so, but the answers are vague and unsatisfying:

- [need to package jinja2 template for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38617900)
- [How to make a python package containing only jinja templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150156)

**How can I load the template directly from the filesystem, not as a resource in a package?**

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Use a `FileSystemLoader` instead of a `PackageLoader`.  Suppose there is a python file in the same directory as the template:

```
./index.py
./template.html
```

This index.py will find the template and render it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import jinja2

templateLoader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(searchpath="./")
templateEnv = jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader)
TEMPLATE_FILE = "template.html"
template = templateEnv.get_template(TEMPLATE_FILE)
outputText = template.render()  # this is where to put args to the template renderer

print(outputText)
```

In the introduction, the `PackageLoader` approach seems to be presented as the default, "simplest" method; however, there is also a [section](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#loaders) which discusses all the built-in loaders.

Comment: Sort of ridiculous you can't load a template from a file in one line e.g. `jinja2.load_template('template.html')`

Comment: I always have a Wrapper that I just call Jinja2 in my applications where I put all this verbosity, then call it like: `Jinja2.render(template_name, data)`

Comment: **Important security risk!** You almost certainly want to call `jinja2.Environment(loader=templateLoader, autoescape=True)`. Or see the [api docs](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/) for more info. Just found out I ended up with a major XSS vulnerability from following this answer :/

Comment: Both links at top are broken.

Answer (score 143):

A simpler way is to directly call the [`jinja2.Template`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Template) constructor and use `open` to load the file:

```
from jinja2 import Template
with open('template.html.jinja2') as file_:
    template = Template(file_.read())
template.render(name='John')
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not allow setting up custom filters. The template loading generates an error during initialization because the custom filter doesn't exist yet. And this way you only have access to the environment (to include the filter) after initialization.

Comment: This gives me `Can't compile non template nodes` on Python 3, likely because `file_.read` returns `bytes` instead of the expected `str | Template` ("expected" as in "expected according to my IDE").

Answer (score 52):

Here is the one liner:

```
from jinja2 import Template

with open('template_file.j2') as f:
    template = Template(f.read())
```

Then you can render the template on another line, or for all in one line:

```
with open('template_file.j2') as f:
    rendered = Template(f.read()).render(var="TEXT")
```

Comment: Sadly this will break if there is template inheritance, as Jinja won't be able to find the  referenced templates.

Comment: But luckily this is simple and enough if you don't use inheritance, and just wan't to send some simple email for example.. :)

Comment: The other major downside to this one liner is that you don't close the file. At worst, this leads to file corruption. Would highly recommend using a python context and making it two lines rather than one!

Comment: @NikhilShinday Failing to close a file that is open for reading (the default mode of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)) will absolutely never lead to file corruption.

Comment: It's not clear to me how this adds anything over Cas's answer.

Comment: @NikhilShinday the `with` context manager closes the file once the template rendering is done. Cf. "https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase" search for "context manager"

Comment: the original post did not use a context manager, but as pointed @JonathonReinhart out, I was incorrect in stating that it would lead to file corruption. The consequences of not calling close() on I/O objects are more related to resource consumption, program unpredictability, and possibly running out of file descriptors on the OS.

Answer (score 22):

If using Python 3.4+ and Jinja2 - v2.11+ -- we can combine python's pathlib and Filesystem to simplify the flow

```
from pathlib import Path
...

p = Path(__file__).parent.parent / 'templates' # sample relative path
env = Environment(
    loader=FileSystemLoader(Path(p)))
template = env.get_template('your_file.jinja2')
```

I am not comfortable with using directly `Template(file)` since Jinja's template inheritance processing may not work well.

Pathlib support is only added in latest version of Jinja - v2.11+

Comment: `Path(p)` is redundant.

Comment: This is a neat solution for when you get your pathname on the command line, and it could be absolute or relative: use `p = Path(sys.argv[1])`, then `FileSystemLoader(p.parent)` and `env.get_template(p.name)`. Works for both relative and absolute pathnames.

Answer (score 2):

```
from jinja2 import Environment, select_autoescape, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader(
searchpath=folder_contain_list_html), autoescape=select_autoescape(['html', 'xml']))

template = env.get_template('file_name_detail_template')

body_html = template.render(**args)

send_email(body_html)
```

Comment: Format your code, provide some context and explain why your answer is better than the accepted one.